# How to make Spring's @Autowired to work in JUnit 5 extensions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I have a Spring Boot application, and I am trying to use `@Autowired` in a JUnit 5 extension. However, I cannot get it to work. (The `@Autowired` field is null.) Can anybody help?

Below is code that demonstrates the problem I'm having (the important parts are `SomeExtension` and `SomeTest`. As written, `mvn test` causes the test to fail in `beforeEach`. Sorry if I'm including too much.

src/test/java/somepackage/SomeExtension.java:

```
package somepackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SomeExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Autowired
    SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        assertNotNull(bean);
    }
}
```

src/test/java/somepackage/SomeTest.java:

```
package somepackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SomeExtension.class)
class SomeTest {
    @Test
    void nothingTest() {
    }
}
```

src/main/java/somepackage/SomeBean.java

```
package somepackage;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeBean {
}
```

src/main/java/somepackage/MainClass.java

```
package somepackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fooGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>barArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- Don't include Junit 4 -->
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!--
                This is copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven
                This allows the surefire plugin to be able to find Junit 5 tests, so `mvn test` works.
                -->
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I'm also having similar issues with `@Value`. If the solution also works for that, it would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: This is essentially a duplicate question, and here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251190/388980

Comment: I just read that question, and I figured out that I just had to add a field to SomeTest with type SomeExtension, and annotate it with @ Autowired and @ RegisterExtension. And I had to annotate SomeExtension with @ Component. Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Glad that helped you. And... you're of course welcome.

Comment: and to add spring context via @ SpringJUnitConfig or just @ ContextConfiguration

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a duplicate, as this question is broader and Sam's is more specific. Can you "unduplicate" this one?

Comment: Maybe my answer would help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61937065/4567218

Answer (score 4):

[JUnit 5 extensions](https://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-extension-model) can not operate on other extensions, just on test classes.

So...

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SomeExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {

    @Autowired
    SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        assertNotNull(bean);
    }

}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SomeExtension.class)
class SomeTest {

    @Test
    void nothingTest() {
    }

}
```

... can not work. This would:

```
public class SomeExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        // [...]
    }

}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SomeExtension.class)
class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeBean bean;

    @Test
    void nothingTest() {
    }

}
```

If you can explain why you need a bean in your extension, we may be able to help you find a fix for that, too.

Comment: I'm trying to add a precondition and postcondition that must be satisfied in every test in every class I specify. My approach was to have an extension implement BeforeEachCallback and AfterEachCallback. Checking the precondition and postcondition requires access to some beans.

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat: Can you edit your question to clarify that use case? While you're at it, you can remove a few things, to make it shorter: all imports and package declarations as well as `SomeBean`, `MainClass` and the POM - they are not needed to answer your question.

Comment: Actually, JUnit Jupiter extensions _can_ possibly interact with other extensions if those other extensions are registered programmatically via `@RegisterExtension`. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251190/388980. ;-)

Comment: Why not just use `SpringExtension.getApplicationContext().getBean(SomeBean.class)` in this case?

Comment: @Torsten +1 Used that approach and it solved exactly my issue.

Comment: @Torsten `getApplicationContext` takes `ExtensionContext` as an argument. What should I pass as `ExtensionContext`?

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown the extensionContext that is passed as argument inside your own extension method, e.g. `SomeExtension::beforeEach` in this answer code. You can't do that in the Test class directly

Comment: Amazing how complicated it is to get Autowired annotations working in tests. In Junit 4 it worked out of the box

Comment: @MarianKlühspies Didn't you need a dedicated runner or rule for that?

Comment: @NicolaiParlog Not sure about that, but it seems that when using SpringBootTest without ExtendsWith the Autowired annotations works as expected

Comment: @MarianKlühspies You may confusing this scenario with the one where you want to inject into a test. That's not what the question (or answer) is about - it's about injecting into an extension. And I don't think that would have been possible in JUnit 4 either. Surely not in a runner (_Highlander rule_) and I suspect neither in a rule.

Comment: @Torsten you should add that as an answer.